# Importxml from Etsy site in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to extract the **sale info** from this link with `importxml`

[link](https://www.etsy.com/shop/1000Lightyear)
[image: sale info]

My formula:

```
substitute(substitute(to_text(index(IMPORTXML(strong textLINK;"//div['before-sticky-nav']//div['trust-signals col-group content   no-banner']//div['show-lg show-xl show-tv shop-info col-lg-7 pl-lg-3']//p['trust-signal-row text-gray-lighter']/span[3]");1));" Sales";"");" Sale";"")
```

The formula has been working for 1 month, yesterday it didn't work. I've tried many variations of the `xpath` still no luck. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY({ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://www.etsy.com/shop/1000Lightyear"), 4000, 1)},
 "WHERE Col1 CONTAINS 'mr-xs-2 pr-xs-2 br-xs-1"">'"), 
 "\>([0-9 A-Za-z]+)\<"),
 " Sales| Sale", ""))
```

[image: 0]